# How to read csv with pandas - line format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have log files which look like this:

```
Datetime;Identifier;Description;Value;Unit 
2020-06-18 00:02:55;var1;Gasflow meting 1;7.494;L/min 
2020-06-18 00:02:55;var2;Dauwpunt meting 1;-53.119;grC  
2020-06-18 00:08:55;var1;Gasflow meting 1;7.494;L/min  
2020-06-18 00:08:55;var2;Dauwpunt meting 1;-53.119;grC
```

This is fundamentally a sort of line (or row) format where instead of getting one columne per variable, every row contains a different variable.

I want to read this with pandas into a column-oriented format. The df should end up looking like:

```
Datetime;[identifier1_description1_unit1];[identifier2_description2_unit2];etc
```

Where the name a of a column is the chaining of the identifier, description and unit as one.

Using the example above, this would be:

```
Datetime;[var1_Gasflow meting 1_L/min];[var2_Dauwpunt meting 1_grC]
2020-06-18 00:02:55;7.494;-53.119
2020-06-18 00:08:55;7.494;-53.119
```

Of course, the log file and list is much longer, without knowing exactly the the names of the identifier, description, value or unit.

Comment: To clarify, for your example columns would go ```"Datetime", "var1", "var2", "Description", "Value" "Unit"``` in your desired output?

Comment: Give sample input and desired output. "should end up looking like..." is not clear.

Comment: Just edited to make more clear!

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', sep=';')
```

this will create a dataframe with the data in the file using ; as the sepator.

Comment: This is not what is requested. I edited the op for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I came across to the most simple solution I believe. I was not familiar with the pivot function of pandas, which does the entire trick:

```
df =  pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')
df['label'] = df['Identifier'] + "_" + df['Description'] + "_" + df['Unit']
df.drop(['Identifier','Description','Unit'],inplace=True)
df2 = df.pivot(index='Datetime', columns='label', values='value')
```

Comment: Solid solution _and_ your own - that's the best that can happen. One observation, hopefully without coming across as nitpicky: If your original frame has, say, 1 million rows then you produce 1 million new column labels, most of them identical. If you group first you do that only 2 times. It most likely won't matter here, but it's good to keep in mind. That's not meant to badmouth your solution, it's solid!

Answer (score 0):

This is not very pythonic

```
df =  pd.read_csv('~/projects/data.txt', sep=';')
```

Yields

```
    Datetime            Identifier  Description     Value   Unit
0   2020-06-18 00:02:55 var1    Gasflow meting 1    7.494   L/min
1   2020-06-18 00:02:55 var2    Dauwpunt meting 1   -53.119 grC
```

then make the label

```
df['label'] = df['Identifier'] + "_" + df['Description'] + "_" + df['Unit']
```

Gets this

```
    Datetime            Identifier  Description     Value   Unit    label
0   2020-06-18 00:02:55 var1    Gasflow meting 1    7.494   L/min   var1_Gasflow meting 1_L/min
1   2020-06-18 00:02:55 var2    Dauwpunt meting 1   -53.119 grC var2_Dauwpunt meting 1_grC
```

Now the bit that is not very pythonic and you will have to put the format the way you like

```
for name, df1 in df.groupby('Datetime'):
    df2 = df1[['label','Value']]
    print (name)
    print (df2['label'].to_list())
    print (df2['Value'].to_list())


2020-06-18 00:02:55
['var1_Gasflow meting 1_L/min', 'var2_Dauwpunt meting 1_grC']
[7.494, -53.119]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion (`file_name` is the path/name of the file):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=';', header=0, index_col=0)

col_group = ['Identifier', 'Description', 'Unit']
df = pd.concat([group.drop(columns=col_group)
                     .rename(columns={'Value': f"[{'_'.join(keys)}]"})
                for keys, group in df.groupby(by=col_group)],
               axis='columns')
```

Result:

```
                     [var1_Gasflow meting 1_L/min]  [var2_Dauwpunt meting 1_grC]
Datetime                                                                        
2020-06-18 00:02:55                          7.494                       -53.119
2020-06-18 00:08:55                          7.494                       -53.119
```

If `Datetime` isn't the index you have to adjust a bit (or set it as index).